# Ubuntu installation fails (USB and DVD)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, nvidia, usb

I'm trying to install Ubuntu with windows 10.

When I boot from USB pendrive or DVD it shows a menu where I can choose to install or try without install. If I choose to try or install it I get a screen saying Ubuntu with five dots orange and white and at that point it freezes. When I'm use an USB flash drive the light turns off and when I'm using DVD it stops running.

I have an Asus laptop with: i5 6300hq; 8GB of ram; 1 TB HDD;Nvidia gtx950m.

Comment: It is due to the enabled secured boot in BIOS. You have to turn it off manually in BIOS settings

Comment: You have a laptop with no BIOS firmware but with UEFI firmware. It is probably configured to boot windows 10 with EFI mode, GPT and secure boot. The last means it mostly only works with windows installs (usually since the keys to that part has leaked, so secure boot is not secure anymore). The validate that this is the problem turn secure boot off and try again.

Comment: i already have secure boot disabled and it doesn't work. Although i didn't belive this would work i tried with another usb and it disn't work as well.